# How to display same picturebox to other forms visual studio c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have FormAct1:

[image]

and FormMain:

[image]

I can't make the picture to be inserted, via user input from FormAct1 and display it in FormMain

Here is my code

```
public static PictureBox usi;

private void ChooseImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // openfiledialog filter
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
        }

        usi = pictureBox1;
    }
    catch 
    {
    }
}
```

I tried searching for similar problems, but to no avail.

What I need to see is that the same picture should appear in `FormMain`.

Comment: A PictureBox is a tool, used to present images. What you need is the *image*, or - as it appears, in this case - the path to an image file. Remove `static` and `public` from the PictureBox Field. You need to return a string from the Form that selects the image. Add a public Property to it (e.g. `string SelectedImagePath { get; }`), so you can read this value from any Form that's showing `FormAct1` -- Possibly, avoid `Image.FromFile()` to load the image in `FormAct1`

Comment: You don't display the same `PictureBox`. You would have separate `PictureBox` controls on each form. You can then take the path selected in your `OpenFileDialog` and assign it to the `ImageLocation` property of each of those controls. The path is just a `string` so you pass that in and out of form objects in exactly the same way as you would in and out of any other objects. If you need to understand how that works, check [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2012/04/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html) out.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , i think im getting what you're saying, so tl;dr i just need to make the imagelocation that is in string to public so that my main form could access it when it loads

Comment: @Jimi so basically what you're saying is that i just need to have the file location be copied and have it transferred to my main form so that when it loads, it will also loads the same picture? gotcha

Comment: You should declare a property on the form that gets the `ImageLocation` of the `PictureBox` in the getter and sets the same in the setter. I call it a pass-through property. Not sure whether others use the same terminology.

Comment: @Jimi i tried the Image.FromFile() which is what you said that i should avoid, `pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(FormAct1.usrImage);` and it works!

Comment: @jmcilhinney can you tell me more? i tried using this get and set but i just can't get the right syntax so i tried doing the Image.FromFile()

Comment: I suggested to avoid `Image.FromFile()` because it locks the image on disk, doesn't consider ICM Color correction and performs a completely useless validation of the image

Comment: How hard can it be? Write a property with a getter and a setter. In the getter, return the control property and in the setter, set the control property. If you can't get it to work, update your question and show us what you did and tell us what happened.